# Find duplicate values in Array and sum them MongoDB Aggregation without using $unwind and $group

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

This is my MongoDB document:

```
{
"name": ClassA1
"data": [
        {
  "first": John,
  "second": David"
  "age": 21,
  "score": 1
   },
    {
  "first": John,
  "second": David"
  "age": 21,
  "score": 1
   },
   {
  "first": John,
  "second": David"
  "age": 22,
  "score": 1
   }
 ]

}
```

What i am trying to achieve here is i want to find if there is repeating "age" (value 21) in data array i want to sum the score field only and copy the other object but without using the $unwind and $group in MongoDB aggregation.
other fields like first, second can be copied as it is and it will be always be same in my case the only different fields will be age and score. i want to compare repeating age and sum the scores in this case my output should be:

```
{
"name": ClassA1
"data": [
        {
  "first": John,
  "second": David"
  "age": 21,
  "score": 2
   },
   {
  "first": John,
  "second": David"
  "age": 22,
  "score": 1
   }
 ]

}
```

As you can see the first element's score is 2 now which is added from the previous one.
I hope you understand.
Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/nyXUMEivMIt
So this is what i have tried:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      values: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$array",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $cond: [
                  {
                    $in: [
                      "$$this.age",
                      "$$value.age"
                    ]
                  },
                  [
                    {
                      "$sum": {
                        "$add": [
                          "$$this.score",
                          "$$value.score"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

this is the error i am getting:

query failed: (Location16554) PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $add only supports numeric or date types, not array

Comment: Kindly show us what you've tried so far and where you're stuck? You can't just expect us to write code for you on `StackOverflow`!

Comment: I am sorry please check the answer below i have posted what i have tried and the most near i am right now.
@h-sifat

Comment: Playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/nyXUMEivMIt

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for it. I just used JavaScript to solve the problem. Here we put the first item with new age in the map and then later if we find another person with that same age we add the score to the previous person object and make the current one undefined. After iteration over this array we filter all the undefined item and return it.

#### Edit:

If you want to run this on mongo playground you need to convert the body of the function to a single line string. Try it here: [Mongo playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z1yt9rYegAG)

```
PipeLine = [
  {
    $match: {
      class: "ClassA1",
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      class: 1,
      data: {
        $function: {
          body: function (data) {
            const map = {};
            data = data.map((item) => {
              if (map[item.age]) map[item.age].score += item.score;
              else {
                map[item.age] = item;
                return item;
              }
            });
            return data.filter((item) => item !== undefined);
          },
          args: ["$data"],
          lang: "js",
        },
      },
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: any better solution then function/

Comment: Can't we use map or reduce in it? functions takes ram on big data.

Comment: I don't know, may be. The algorithm I found that first we need to find `objects` in `data` with equal age. If you want to do that with a traditional for loop then you've to traverse the whole `data` array for every single item and that would be `O(n^2)` time complexity but it's true that it would take `O(1)` space in memory. And I don't see a great memory consumption here because we are storing just the `object reference` in that `map` object. It's not like we are deep cloning all the items and making a copy of them. If memory consumption exceeds  `100mb` limit use the `allowDiskuse` option.

Comment: But please let me know if you find a better algorithm. I would love to learn how to make this query more efficient.

Comment: I think i might have explained better here: 
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/i-have-an-array-i-want-to-push-keys-on-each-value-and-also-want-to-count-how-many-times-they-were-repeated-using-aggregation/120279

Comment: @BrutalJazzy But where is the answer for that post in that link?

Comment: By the way have have you really tried the above solution? What's the outcome? And one thing I'm curious about is how that duplicate record got into that `data` array? You could have just updated each record at the time of insertion! Or this data comes from somewhere else?

Comment: no solution without wind lol
https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-convert-primitive-array-into-object-array-with-key-and-value/120169/9